# What is this wound on my dog's nose?

Tags: dogs, injury, skin-condition

Any idea as to what this is? it started happening about 3-4 days ago. we think it might be something in his kennel so we have been making him sleep in a different room, but it keeps getting worse over night.

[image]

Comment: i think you need to ask your vet about this,it does not look like an bacterial innfection and it looks nice and clean.

Comment: Assuming he's had his shots, it looks like a skin condition. Vet time.

Answer (score 7):

Take to vet immediately. You don’t want this to get infected and it needs to be taken care of so it doesn’t get any worse.